# Windows 10: Find and focus opened app across multiple desktops

Tags: windows-10

I use Windows 10 multiple desktops feature. Problem is I often have 4+ desktops, then it becomes annoying and time consuming to find where is the app I previously opened again. Oftentimes, I just give up and re-open the app on the current desktop rather than search for it, not ideal for resources etc. Is there a smarter way to find it?

**EDIT:**  Ideally, I'd like to search by string, for example type 3-4 letters to bring up a short drop-down list of matching opened apps. I tend to avoid mouse use if possible, often I rather use the Windows key search feature (Cortana I think) to open apps rather than using the mouse to pick them from start menu.

Comment: Did some searching, found related apps `Windows Focus Logger` & `Active Window Logger` on github. But neither had a search & focus built-in, which is what I'd like. So maybe i'll try building my own... Suprised there's nothing for this yet, built-in or otherwise. An important usability feature.

Answer (score 1):

[WindowWalker](https://github.com/betsegaw/windowwalker/) that is now part of [PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/powertoys/run) (which needs the .Net Core Desktop Runtime) achieves this.

Comment: AWESOME, many thanks!!!  Actually, it's now called **_PowerToys Run_**. I had been using it but didn't notice this cool feature (`< search terms`).  PowerToys is a great set of tools, I just wish there'd be more docs & tutorials for lazy / part-time coders like me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you do Windows + Tab key, it will bring up a list of desktops and open applications on that desktop.  Hover your mouse over the other desktops to be able to see what applications are on it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a keyboard only solution with search by string capability to limit results, otherwise I lose too much time "scanning" visually accross so many windows.